# how to get text of the latest post with BeautifulSoup, select()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to get the latest posts text using BeautifulSoup and select() method.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'
url = "https:// " 
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = req.text       
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')                
link = soup.select('#flagList > div.clear.ab-webzine > div > a')       
title = soup.select('#flagList > div.clear.ab-webzine > div > div.wz-item-header > a > span')         
latest_link = link[0] # link of latest post    
latest_title = title[0].text # title of latest post

# to get the text of latest post
t_url = latest_link
t_req = requests.get(t_url, headers=headers)
t_html = c_res.text
t_soup = BeautifulSoup(t_html, 'html.parser')  
maintext = t_soup.select ('#flagArticle > div.document_1234567_0.rhymix_content.xe_content')

print(maintext)
```

It returns [].

I copied `#flagArticle > div.document_1234567_0.rhymix_content.xe_content`  from chrome developer tools on the posts.
 so it has specific post number "1234567"
But I want the text of "latest post" not certain post.

So I changed it to just `#flagArticle`

And it returns as below.

```
[<article id="flagArticle">
<!--BeforeDocument(1234567,0)-->
<div class="document_1234567_0 rhymix_content xe_content"><p>TEXTTEXTTEXT 1</p>
<p>TEXTTEXTTEXT 2</p>
<p>TEXTTEXTTEXT 3</p></div><!--AfterDocument(1234567,0)-->
<!--
        -- color class --
        vb-white
        vb-green
        vb-blue
        vb-skyblue
        vb-orange
        vb-red
-->
<div class="vote">
<button class="vb-btn vb-orange" onclick="vote_doVote('Up','1234567');return false;" type="button">
<span class="lang">
<i class="fas fa-star fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
                                recommended            </span>
<span class="num" id="vm_v_count">
                        4               </span>
</button> <button class="vb-btn vb-skyblue" onclick="vote_doVote('Declare','1234567');return false;" type="button">
<span class="lang">
<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
                        report            </span>
<span class="num" id="vm_d_count">
</span>
</button></div> </article>]
```

But I want to get

```
TEXTTEXTTEXT 1
TEXTTEXTTEXT 2
TEXTTEXTTEXT 3
```

What should I change?
(I can't share the URL because it's private site)

Comment: Seems you dealing with JavaScript website, may you share the site itself ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share it because it's private site @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the first `div`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<article id="flagArticle">
<!--BeforeDocument(1234567,0)-->
<div class="document_1234567_0 rhymix_content xe_content"><p>TEXTTEXTTEXT 1</p>
<p>TEXTTEXTTEXT 2</p>
<p>TEXTTEXTTEXT 3</p></div><!--AfterDocument(1234567,0)-->
<!--
        -- color class --
        vb-white
        vb-green
        vb-blue
        vb-skyblue
        vb-orange
        vb-red
-->
<div class="vote">
<button class="vb-btn vb-orange" onclick="vote_doVote('Up','1234567');return false;" type="button">
<span class="lang">
<i class="fas fa-star fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
                                recommended            </span>
<span class="num" id="vm_v_count">
                        4               </span>
</button> <button class="vb-btn vb-skyblue" onclick="vote_doVote('Declare','1234567');return false;" type="button">
<span class="lang">
<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
                        report            </span>
<span class="num" id="vm_d_count">
</span>
</button></div> </article>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

div = soup.select_one('#flagArticle div.xe_content.rhymix_content')
for p in div.select('p'):
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: I wonder why the order changed.
If ```document_1234567_0```is deleted from ```#flagArticle > div.document_1234567_0.rhymix_content.xe_content```
It becomes ```#flagArticle > div.rhymix_content.xe_content``` 
But your answer is
```#flagArticle div.xe_content.rhymix_content```

Comment: That's just to demonstrate that the order of class names does not matter when using CSS selectors. I'm glad you noticed it.

Comment: I didn't know the order isn't important! Thank you for letting me know :D